# illegal base64 data at input byte 8

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Trying to apply deployment.yaml but I got error illegal base64 data at input byte 8.

In my config.json

```
"auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "16c...ad7"
        }
    }
```

I have put token from the docker hub

Register the secret

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=C:\Users\Herman\.docker\config.json --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

in my .yaml my imagePullSecrets: - name: regcred

anybody can help?

Comment: Is the content of `config.json` all surrounded by `{}` or is it as posted in the question `"auths":.....`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't create Secret in Kubernetes: illegal base64 data at input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394973/cant-create-secret-in-kubernetes-illegal-base64-data-at-input)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the the `oauth2accesstoken` part wasn't base64 encoded as well. So once I made sure that part was also base64 encoded, along with the token in the same string, it worked.

**Example Setup for oAuth and GCR**

```
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)
export BASE_64_GCR_AUTH_TOKEN=$(echo "oauth2accesstoken:${ACCESS_TOKEN}" | base64 -w 0)
```